# How to make Bootstrap rows expand the DIV they are in?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to use Bootstrap to make a panel with a four rows of checkboxes in it.

In the following code, `adminPanel` has a border around it but the Bootstrap content does not expand the div:

[image]

If I had normal HTML, it works fine.

**How can I get Bootstrap rows to expand the DIV they are located in?**

```css
.adminPanel {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="adminPanel">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Testing</label>
      </div> 
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Testing</label>
      </div> 
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Testing</label>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Testing</label>
      </div> 
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Testing</label>
      </div> 
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Testing</label>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Testing</label>
      </div> 
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Testing</label>
      </div> 
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Testing</label>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Testing</label>
      </div> 
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Testing</label>
      </div> 
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Testing</label>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to increase the font size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've converted your `.col-sm-12` into a `.row` and surrounded it with a `.container` making it use a correct Bootstrap grid structure. Always have an outer `.container` and combine the usage of columns with rows. Nesting these would lead to a structure like `.container > .row > .col-... > .row > .col-...`.

However that's not the issue here. All columns float and won't take up space in the document. This makes the `.adminPanel` have a height of zero. Either add a `.clearfix` to the `.adminPanel`, or as I've done move the `.adminPanel` to the `.row` class which has a clearfix built in.

```css
.adminPanel {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row adminPanel">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="" />Testing</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="" />Testing</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="" />Testing</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="" />Testing</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="" />Testing</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="" />Testing</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="" />Testing</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="" />Testing</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="" />Testing</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="" />Testing</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="" />Testing</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="" />Testing</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
display: inline-block;
```

to the class .adminPanel in your CSS file.

Comment: Don't do this if you want to use Bootstraps grid inside the `.adminPanel` as it won't make the columns take up 100% of the `.container`

Comment: Ok. Didn't think of that. Your solution would've been my second approach (not in that detail, but the core part -> just add "adminPanel" to the parent element to define the border there.